# How to handle error response with Retrofit 2

Tags: android, firebase, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Firebase REST API for my auth logic. I am using MVVM pattern for my project. I can get two different types of responses. One of them successful one of them is error. I get successful response only email and password correct. Other times I get error response. I can handle successful Response but I couldn't handle error response.

Here is my example Error Response which I get from Postman :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalid"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And this is successful response

```
{
    "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
    "localId": "c5Tbai1nG7U****",
    "email": "muratcan*****",
    "displayName": "",
    "idToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjQ4OTQ5ZDdkNDA3ZmVjOWIyYWM4ZDYzNWVjYmEwYjdhOTE0ZWQ4ZmIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3V****",
    "registered": true,
    "refreshToken": "AOvuKvSHOlnUg9O94OvADakpm5r7hXLP32k6WdBqIfTiLZHq-MVXnQcegBrRY3Pd1UjtO4WOTVv4****",
    "expiresIn": "3600"
}
```

I can access successful response like email , registered , idToken etc.
But I  want to get message from error response. Which is "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD" ( for this example of course it can get another values like Email not found etc.)

This is my Response Class.

```
data class SignInWithEmailResponse(
    @SerializedName("kind")
    var kind: String = "",

    @SerializedName("localId")
    var localId: String = "",

    @SerializedName("email")
    var email: String = "",

    @SerializedName("displayName")
    var displayName: String = "",

    @SerializedName("idToken")
    var idToken: String = "",

    @SerializedName("registered")
    var registered: Boolean = false,

    @SerializedName("refreshToken")
    var refreshToken: String = "",

    @SerializedName("expiresIn")
    var expiresIn: String = ""

)
```

And here is my login method.

```
class LoginScreenViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    //some other declarations which are not important for this question

    fun login(email: String, password: String) {
        if (isEmailValid(email) && isPasswordValid(password)) {
            loginAuth(email, password)
        } else {
            loginSuccessLiveData.postValue(false)
        }

    }

    private fun loginAuth(username: String, password: String) {

        val loginService = ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService::class.java, username, password)
        val call: Call<Any> = loginService.loginWithEmail(SignInWithEmailRequest(username, password))

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<Any> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<Any>,
                response: Response<Any?>
            ) {

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    loginSuccessLiveData.postValue(true)
                    val gsonVal = Gson().toJson(response.body())
                    val deGsonVal = Gson().fromJson(gsonVal, SignInWithEmailResponse::class.java)
                    Log.d("response", deGsonVal.toString()) // I can get my values correctly
                } else {
                    loginSuccessLiveData.postValue(false)
                    val gsonVal = Gson().toJson(response.errorBody())
                    val deGsonVal = Gson().fromJson(gsonVal, SignInWithEmailError::class.java)
                    Log.d("response", deGsonVal.message) // application crashes
                }
            }
 
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<SignInWithEmailResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                //connectivity Error handle
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And this is my response. I get this data with debugging. But I can't read that data. I mark it with red.

[image: Response with debugging]

Here is my Login service interface

```
interface LoginService {

    @POST(postValue) //api end point is declared outside of class. Not important for this question
    fun loginWithEmail(@Body request:SignInWithEmailRequest): Call<SignInWithEmailResponse>
}
```

I also tried to create a class like SignInWithEmailResponse. It's name is SignInWithEmailError. I put a String variable in it which name is message. But I couldn't put this in my code. I use this lines for my calls.

```
call: Call<SignInWithEmailResponse>,
response: Response<SignInWithEmailResponse?>
```

I couldn't figure out how to implement SignInWithEmailError class anywhere in this call.

**UPDATE**

Here is the Error Response class.

```
data class SignInWithEmailError(
    @SerializedName("errors")
    var errors: Errors = Errors(),

    @SerializedName("code")
    var code: Int = 0,

    @SerializedName("message")
    var message: String =""

)
```

Comment: Most likely you should create a class called [DataOrException](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreJetpackCompose/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firestorejetpackcompose/data/DataOrException.kt) and populate the fields either with the data or the Exception.

Comment: Yes I do that. I write that but I am editing my question to include this part too. I have a Error class but I couldn't make it work. I am updating my question right now